# Immediate 'preview' of selected file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In the past, when I had been working with a Visual Studio (2010 that was, I believe), I came around this feature that I has been trying to get for past few months but cannot find reference of anywhere - VS settings/extensions/Google search etc.

As far as I know, this is what I remember.

When I selected a file in Solution Explorer, the file got immediately shown in special 'preview' window. This window changed it's content according to what file was selected in Solution Explorer. Once there were some changes in the file content (e.g. when I typed in some new text or deleted some), it appeared as a common edit window. This 'preview' window held content of last selected unchanged file and it's tab was located on the **right** side of the upper border, not on the left side as is usual for common edit windows.

The cons was that I could see the contents of every selected file without the need to clutter the tab panel with a lot of useless opened edit windows without the need to close them.

Thank you for any hint where to get this kind of behavior.

Comment: The preview tab was added to VS 2012. You can't get it in VS 2010.

Comment: Oh heck. Thanks. I dunno why I could not find it though. Wrong search terms I guess.